# C# private declaration after static?

Tags: c#

When I was coding I accidentally pasted private after static it gave me no error code, I expected it would have a compile error but all was fine. Why is this?

```
static private bool example(char c) { }
```

Comment: Why should it be a problem?

Comment: maybe because order doesn't matter?